# Why can't I get two <p> elements to be side-by-side and aligned by center?

Tags: html, css

Here is a blue print of what I am **trying** to do:

[image: blueprint]

As you can see, I want to move the two texts to the center of there input box.

HTML:

```
<p id="win">On win:</p>
<p id="lose">On lose:</p>
<input class="default" id="onwin" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
<input class="default" id="onlose" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I tried to do this with no luck:

```
<p style="text-align: center;" id="win">On win:</p>
<p style="text-align: center;float: left;" id="lose">On lose:</p>
<input class="default" id="onwin" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
<input class="default" id="onlose" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Y4F.png)

CSS for input:

```
input[class="default"] {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `float`s and `text-align` you can achieve it:

```css
body {text-align: center;}
#win, #lose {width: 50%; float: left; text-align: center;}
#lose {float: right;}
.default {display: inline-block; width: 45%; padding: 3px;}
```

```html
<p id="win">On win:</p>
<p id="lose">On lose:</p>
<input class="default" id="onwin" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
<input class="default" id="onlose" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: Hi there, I like this solution but where did you get the 50-45 width ratio? I'd like to keep the width the same as the above example,

Comment: @quad Just for this example bro. You can have whatever you want. 50-50 is totally fine. Just go ahead. `:D`

Comment: This is the cleanest solution here, so I'll accept it.

Comment: @quad Thanks mate. Have a nice day ahead. Let me know if you are stuck in anyway...

Comment: Just one more question, why exactly does the text become uncentered if I change the width to 40% on .default and 45% on #win, #lose? http://prntscr.com/g5s0e7

Comment: @quad Can you make a [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com) code and send to me?

Answer (score 0):

Give both `p` elements the `float: left;` style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a block with the input and the title.

```css
body
{
  text-align:center;
}

input[class="default"] {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

#lose,#win
{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div  id="win">
  <p>On win:</p>
  <input class="default" id="onwin" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>

<div id="lose">
  <p>On lose:</p>
  <input class="default" id="onlose" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flexbox for a div around the paragraphs and the inputs.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

input[class="default"] {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <p id="win">On win:</p>
  <p id="lose">On lose:</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input class="default" id="onwin" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off" />
  <input class="default" id="onlose" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for me is to use `flex` along with containers : it will not mess with your DOM (like `float` does eg. child elements can get bigger than their parent). So i'll go with :

```css
  #flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  input[class="default"] {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">

  <div class="container">
      <p id="win">On win:</p>
      <input class="default" id="onwin" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="lose">On lose:</p>
    <input class="default" id="onlose" placeholder="%" value="0" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>

</div>
```